# Label not displaying the dropdownlist selected value

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

VS is giving error at  this line:
Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

Error message says that object reference not set to an instance of the object. what could be the solution?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Login
{
    public partial class ViewCourses : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string loginID = Convert.ToString(Session[0]);
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = loginID;
            Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;

Nothing is initially selected in the dropdown list (when the Page has been loaded), so DropDownList1.SelectedItem is null.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that `DropDownList1.SelectedItem` is `null`.

Put a breakpoint on that line and see what `DropDownList1.SelectedItem`'s value is.

Are you familiar with the VS debugger and breakpoints?

Comment: Great, glad your problem has been solved and welcome to StackOverflow! If you find an answer useful, then please accept the answer.